# Spring boot yml configuration

Tags: spring-boot

With Spring Boot, you can specify the following in a `application.yml` to configure settings for jpa/hibernate:

```
spring:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddlAuto: validate
      namingStrategy: org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy
    show-sql: false
```

My question: is there a page/doc that lists out all the different configs that can be defined in the application.yml? (i.e. Where does it say I can configure jpa/hibernate by the above example?)

Comment: Luckily for you Spring Boot happens to have [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a section in the official documention:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Do you know if that's the official list? Because it says that it's a sample file.

Comment: Well, I guess its not an exhaustive list but it includes the classes that consume the parameters. So you could go to the source of the class that you are interested in and check what other properties it has.